# Java Scanner delimiter on values of nextLine

Tags: java

I have a file in .dat format. Here is a sample

> ||= (N              ) =||    1||  0.938  ||   ---    ||   0.5  ||  (****)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     0    ||  0.700  ||  (p)=2212, (n)=2112  ||
>
> ||= (\Delta         ) =||    2||  1.232  ||   0.118  ||   1.5  ||  (****)||     1.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  (\Delta^{++})=2224, (\Delta^+)=2214, (\Delta^0)=2114, (\Delta^-)=1114  ||
>
> ||= (P_{11}(1440)   ) =||    3||  1.462  ||   0.391  ||   0.5  ||  (****)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  202212, 202112  ||
>
> ||= (S_{11}(1535)   ) =||    4||  1.534  ||   0.151  ||   0.5  ||  ( ***)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  102212, 102112  ||

I am trying to use Scanner to read this file and delimit the line by the "||" and then send into and ArrayList for future processing. Here is a sample of my code where I use the delimiter

```
String file = "data.dat";
Scanner s = null;
try {
    s = new Scanner(new File(file)).useDelimiter("\\|\\|"); //here is the use of my delimiter

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {   //notice I am using hasNextLine because each line must be unique to create the HashMap 
        list.add(s.nextLine());
    }
    s.close();
    for (String string : list) {  //Lets print out the values of the list
        System.out.println(string);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But my output still has values of the delimiter, i.e. here is the output:

> ||= (N              ) =||    1||  0.938  ||   ---    ||   0.5  ||  (****)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     0    ||  0.700  ||  (p)=2212, (n)=2112  ||
>
> ||= (\Delta         ) =||    2||  1.232  ||   0.118  ||   1.5  ||  (****)||     1.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  (\Delta^{++})=2224, (\Delta^+)=2214, (\Delta^0)=2114, (\Delta^-)=1114  ||
>
> ||= (P_{11}(1440)   ) =||    3||  1.462  ||   0.391  ||   0.5  ||  (****)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  202212, 202112  ||
>
> ||= (S_{11}(1535)   ) =||    4||  1.534  ||   0.151  ||   0.5  ||  ( ***)||     0.5   ||      0   ||     0    ||     3    ||  1.076  ||  102212, 102112  ||

I have searched and found no answer that helped. I am also seeing a warning about a "Resource leak: '' is never closed" with the line

```
s = new Scanner(new File(file)).useDelimiter("\\|\\|");
```

which disappears if the line is broken into

```
s = new Scanner(new File(file));
s.useDelimiter("\\|\\|");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. That's because a line might not necessarily end with `||`.

Comment: @progy_rock nextLine is essential because every line is an array of values I need to sort later. Using next(), will lose the placement of the idenity.

Comment: Why not read each line with your scanner without delimiter. And then use String.split on each line with your Delimiter?

Comment: @mkunkel The way you are proceeding,you are trying to satisfy two mutually exclusive conditions at the same time. As I said, "_a line might not necessarily end with `||`_". A line is one that ends with a `\n`. There might be `||`s before the end of a line; how do we know there isnt?

Comment: @ArcticLord I could do it that way. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @progy_rock I do not see how this processes is doubly mutually exclusive. Scanner has the method nextLine() and also the method useDelimiter().

Comment: It is. Look. `useDelimiter()` makes the object break the entire String into tokens. It's similar to using `split("||")`. In order to get each token, you need to use `next()`.`nextLine()` returns a line irrespective of any delimiters; in fact it considers only `\n` as the delimiter. You are considering every `||` separated token as a line but technically, that's not the case.

Comment: @progy_rock, you might be interested in this comment of the OP from one of the answers `I need to use nextLine(), not next(). Later I will be comparing values of the array for each line with some logic. So I need nextLine().` So clearing, there is a lack of information here. If the OP need to work on a line later, it simply need to remove the delimiter. Using a split to create his array. The array will be a full line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use backslash escape. instead of `\\|\\|` as your delimiter, just split the string after it's read from the file.

```
String file = "data.dat";
Scanner s = null;
try {
    s = new Scanner(new File(file)); //no more delimiter. It's not needed
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {

        String[] strings = s.nextLine().split("[||]");
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            list.add(strings[i]);   
        }
    }
    s.close();
    for (String string : list) {  //Lets print out the values of the list
        System.out.println(string);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should fix it.

Comment: I have modified to your recommendation and this did not work. I get the same output as before.

Comment: just a second. testing it again

Comment: I see what you did there. I need to use nextLine(), not next(). Later I will be comparing values of the array for each line with some logic. So I need nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

You can just read the line without delimiter, and then replace `||` with whatever you want using [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method.

Code

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String newLine = s.nextLine().replace("||","");
        list.add(newLine);
         // or just like this
        //list.add(s.nextLine().replace("||",""));
    }
    s.close();

    for (String string : list) { 
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Check the output [here](http://ideone.com/m6qmUf).

Comment: @mkunkel My pleasure, note that you can avoid inner for loop if you use replace instead of split and which in turn might increase performance for large file.